# future vs future continuous

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, future-tense, future-perfect

> **The movie about the cursed child would have been made by 2020.**

Or

> **The movie about the cursed child would be made by 2020.**

I want to know which of the sentences will hold good if the movie was to be shooted by 2020.

Comment: Both sentences are perfectly grammatical. Beyond that, more context is needed to analyse them, though they both may well be the apodoses in remote conditionals.

Comment: *Would have been made* is not "future continuous"; it's "future perfect."

Answer (score -1):

Neither sentence is grammatical. If the sentences are intended to be uttered now, namely before 2020, then they should be in the future and use "will." If the sentences are intended to be uttered after 2020, they need to be in the simple past or else be part of a conditional sentence. If the implied question is whether "will have been made" or "will be made" is the better choice, I note that this involves the perfect aspect of the verb and that both choices are acceptable though personally I prefer the future perfect over the simple future in this example.

Comment: While I agree that the use of "will" is better for what the OP is trying to say, I'm not sure I agree that "neither sentence is grammatical."

Comment: @JR I tried to explain why I thought both sentences would be ungrammatical. Before 2020, they should be in a future tense. After 2020, the constructions using "would" need to an "if" clause to explain under what circumstances the statements would have been true. If you would be so kind as to explain what would make the sentences grammatical, I shall happily change my answer and acknowledge your assistance.

Comment: Both sentences are perfectly grammatical. They are looking back from after 2020 to a time before 2020 when the movie was being planned or begun. In the first case the movie was not in fact made, in the second, it was. The first could also have an epistemic reading, along the lines of "I deduce or remember that the movie was made by 2020".

Comment: Of course this question was posed in **2017.** As of the time of asking, “will” rather than “would” is appropriate. Even if the sentence was intended to be made after 2019, it cannot be a **stand-alone** sentence because, from 2020 on, the movie was either produced or else not produced.before then. Only as part of a more complex sentence, such as “I believed that it would be made by 2020,” is the clause grammatical . But the question asked about a sentence in isolation.